# Disable dataLabel if its width is more than height of its bar in highCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have created a chart using HighCharts and I want to disable any dataLabel if its width is more than height of its bar(bar cannot accomodate the dataLabel). I set the property 'enabled : false' of dataLabel of particular points but the effect is not being reflected in the chart.[image: Here is the image of properties where 'enabled' is false for one of the points]

[image: Here is the image of chart where points with y :- 10700 , 20300 and 20000 should have been disabled]

```html
<html>

<body>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


<script language="javascript">
         
var pointSelected = {};
var pointHovered = {};
//Highcharts.chart('container', 

 var chartObject = {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',

        events : {

                    render : function(){

                                var ch = this;
                                var series = this.series;

                                ch.series.forEach(function(s){

                                        s.points.forEach(function(point){

                                                 var barHeight = point.graphic.element.height.animVal.value;
                                                 var dataLabelWidth = point.dataLabel.width;
                                                 var plotBoxWidth = ch.plotBox.width;
                                                console.log(plotBoxWidth);
                                                  if(barHeight + dataLabelWidth < plotBoxWidth)  {

                                                      //  console.log(barHeight + dataLabelWidth);
                                                       // console.log("point will lie inside");

                                                  }
                                                  //else{

                                                  if(dataLabelWidth > barHeight){

                                                       //USING JQUERY IT CAN BE DONE BUT I WANT TO AVOID JQUERY AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE $(point.dataLabel.element).fadeOut("fast");
                                                             point.dataLabel.alignOptions.enabled = false; //THIS IS WHERE I'M DISABLING POINT
                                                                console.log(point)
                                                               // point.update({dataLabels : {enabled : false}});
                                                        //ch.options.plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled = false;
        

                                                  }
                                               
                                               
                                                if(barHeight + dataLabelWidth > plotBoxWidth){

                                                    //   console.log(barHeight + dataLabelWidth);
                                                        var diff = barHeight + dataLabelWidth - plotBoxWidth;
                                                      //  console.log(diff);
                                                       //  var x = point.dataLabel.translateX;
                                                       // var y = point.dataLabel.translateY;
                                                     //   console.log(x);
                                                     //   console.log(point);
                                                    //// diff +=15;
                                                         var diff2 = barHeight - dataLabelWidth;
                                                        // console.log("diff2" + diff2);
                                                        point.dataLabel.translate(  diff2 , point.dataLabel.alignAttr.y );
                                                     //    console.log(   point.dataLabel.text);
                                                     //point.dataLabel.stork("black");
                                                        // point.dataLabel.text.styles.fill = "black";
                                                       var elem =   $(point.dataLabel.element).children();
                                                       $(elem).eq(0).css("fill" , "black");
                                                 
                                                       // console.log(elem);
                                                         // $(textElem).attr("style" , "fill : black");
                                                         // console.log(textElem);
                                                      //   $(point.dataLabel.element.innerHTML).eq(0).children().eq(0).text();
                                                          //  console.log("point will lie outside");
                                                        }
                                                        
                                             //     }




                                        })

                                })
                                console.log(this);


                    }



        }
        
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
       
       formatter : function(){
       
           return '<b>' +this.series.name + '<br/>' +this.x + '<br/>' + this.y+ '000000</b>'
       
       }
       
       },
    plotOptions: {
              series : {

                    allowPointSelect : true,
                    dataLabels: {
                                    enabled : true,
                                    color : "blue",
                                    crop : true,
                                    overflow:  "none"
                                    

                                    },
                                  
            point:{

                    events : {
                                select :function() {

                                        //get the selected object
                                        pointSelected.categories = this.category;
                                        pointSelected.y = this.y;
                                       console.log(this);
                                        
                                      
                                       
                                        changeOpacity(pointSelected);
                                    
                                },
                                mouseOver : function(){

                                        //get the hovered object
                                        pointHovered.categories = this.category;
                                          pointHovered.y = this.y;

                                       
                                         changeOpacityOnHover(pointHovered);


                                }, 
                                mouseOut : function(){

                                        //event handler when mouse moves out
                                        changeOpacityOnOut(pointHovered);


                                }

                    }

            }
                    

            

            
           

             }
       
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        layout: 'vertical',
        x: -150,
        y: 100,
        },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [10700, 45000, 45000, 20300, 20000],
        zones : [{value : 100  , color : 'orange'} , {value : 500  , color : 'black'} , { color : 'blue'}]
    }]
}


//debugger
var barChart = new Highcharts.chart('container', chartObject); 


//function on mouseOver
function changeOpacityOnHover(pointHovered){

    //get the current chart object
    var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
    //get the points and check each point whether it is the hovered one    
    chart.series.forEach(function(obj){

        obj.data.forEach(function(datum){

                    //if hovered one then get its graphic element(rect) and change its opacity to 1
                   if(datum.category == pointHovered.categories && datum.y == pointHovered.y ){

//                            console.log(datum)   ; 

  //                          console.log(datum.graphic.element);

                            var tag = datum.graphic.element;
                            var x = $(tag).attr("x");
//                            console.log(x);
                            $(tag).css("opacity" , "1");
                           
                   }
        });

    })



}

function changeOpacityOnOut(pointHovered){

    //get the current chart object
     var chart = $("#container").highcharts();

     //get the points and check each point whether it is the hovered one from which mouse is over   
    chart.series.forEach(function(obj){
        obj.data.forEach(function(datum){
                    //get its graphic element(rect) 
                   if(datum.category == pointHovered.categories && datum.y == pointHovered.y ){

                         //   console.log(datum)   ; 

                           // console.log(datum.graphic.element);

                            var tag = datum.graphic.element;
                            var x = $(tag).attr("x");
                           // console.log(x);
                            
                            //if the current point(hovered) is selected one OR no point is yet selected , opacity will be 1
                            if((pointHovered.categories == pointSelected.categories && pointHovered.y== pointSelected.y) || Object.keys(pointSelected).length == 0 )
                            {

                                    $(tag).css("opacity" , "1");
                     
                            }
                            //else change opacity to 0.1
                            else{

                                    $(tag).css("opacity" , "0.1");
                     
                            }
                            

                   }
                 
        });

    })






}


// if point is selected
function changeOpacity(pointSelected){

    //get the current chart object
    var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
    
    //get the selected point by comparing each point to pointSelected
    chart.series.forEach(function(obj){

        obj.data.forEach(function(datum){

                    // if current point is selected point then change opacity to 1 and its color to the color of its rect tag fill attribute
                   if(datum.category == pointSelected.categories && datum.y == pointSelected.y){

                           console.log(datum)   ; 

                           // console.log(datum.graphic.element);

                            var tag = datum.graphic.element;
                            //var xVal =   datum.graphic.element.x.animVal.value;
                            //var yVal =   datum.graphic.element.y.animVal.value
                            //console.log(xVal);
                            //console.log(yVal);
                                
                       
                            var x = $(tag).attr("x");
                           //console.log(x);
                          // var x2 = xVal -1;
                           // console.log(datum.dataLabel.translate(xVal , yVal - 1));
                            //console.log("after");
                      // console.log(x2);
                            //console.log(yVal-1);
                            
                                       
                            $(tag).css("opacity" , "1");
                            var color = $(tag).attr("fill");
                            $(tag).css("fill" , color);
                           // console.log(color + "when clicked");
                            

                   }
                   //else let its opacity be 0.1
                   else{

                        var tag = datum.graphic.element;
                        $(tag).css("opacity" , "0.1");

                       

                         }

            
        });

    })


}
</script>






</body>

    
</html>
```

I have solved the problem using jQuery but if it can be done simply by setting property that will be great. Also , why the effect is not being reflected if the property is set??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with your configuration, this is how dataLabels should be configured:

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      crop: true,
      overflow: 'none',
      // inside: true // by default it's outside the bar
    }
  }
},
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/pbjpr47t/

Comment: I have configured in the similar way that you have mentioned.You can see the config object. But if dataLabel is not accomodated by bar , I'm making its enabled property false as shown above in my code but effect is not observed.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you have some old version of Highcharts? As you can see, my demo works fine. If you could recreate issue in jsFiddle then I would be able to see what happens there.